# Entity Framework, Offline Use Strategies?

Tags: c#, winforms, serialization, entity-framework-4

I am currently learning about EF and have come into a scenario where the data should be used in both an online and offline mode.

It is assumed that the user will have to use the system first while connected to obtain the data used offline.

I thought about serializing the queries but IQueryable/ObjectQuery are not marked as serializable.

How would I go about being able to store results from a few queries locally and then restoring them in offline mode so the use can continue to use the app?  I could spend days researching this but I hope somebody can point me in the right direction.

*EDIT*

It is worth noting that the master SQL Server instance is a shared server that has very minimal features installed.  Replication for example, is not installed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, you vcould take a look at SQL server compact.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff687142.aspx

You could copy data from your main DB into a locally stored CE database then switch to this for offline.

Comment: This is a good option.  Unfortunately in this particular scenario creating publications on this instance of SQL Server is not permitted nor is it even installed.  This instance is shared by other production applications and I was given the big double thumbs down so I only got to test this on my local dev machine in an SQL Express instance.  One drawback is that publication runs once daily and in this case the snapshots really need to be up to the minute.  I'm sure there is a function or call somewhere to force it to take a snapshot though.

Comment: If the worst came to the worst you could do the snapshot yourself using EF.